# add arabic language to emulator language settings android 2.2

Tags: android, emulation, multilingual

My emulator android 2.2 have english and japanese language only, and i want to add arabic to the language in settings

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately Arabic is supported from 2.3 up. So you can't use arabic.

Here is a list of supported languages:

> ```
> Language / Locale                 Supported since version
>
> English, US (en_US)               1.1
> German, Germany (de_DE)           1.1
> Chinese, PRC (zh_CN)              1.5
> Chinese, Taiwan (zh_TW)           1.5
> Czech, Czech Republic (cs_CZ)     1.5
> Dutch, Belgium (nl_BE)            1.5
> Dutch, Netherlands (nl_NL)        1.5
> English, Australia (en_AU)        1.5
> English, Britain (en_GB)          1.5
> English, Canada (en_CA)           1.5
> English, New Zealand (en_NZ)      1.5
> English, Singapore(en_SG)         1.5
> French, Belgium (fr_BE)           1.5
> French, Canada (fr_CA)            1.5
> French, France (fr_FR)            1.5
> French, Switzerland (fr_CH)       1.5
> German, Austria (de_AT)           1.5
> German, Liechtenstein (de_LI)     1.5
> German, Switzerland (de_CH)       1.5
> Italian, Italy (it_IT)            1.5
> Italian, Switzerland (it_CH)      1.5
> Japanese (ja_JP)                  1.5
> Korean (ko_KR)                    1.5
> Polish (pl_PL)                    1.5
> Russian (ru_RU)                   1.5
> Spanish (es_ES)                   1.5
> Arabic, Egypt (ar_EG)             2.3
> Arabic, Israel (ar_IL)            2.3
> Bulgarian, Bulgaria (bg_BG)       2.3
> Catalan, Spain (ca_ES)            2.3
> Croatian, Croatia (hr_HR)         2.3
> Danish, Denmark(da_DK)            2.3
> English, India (en_IN)            2.3
> English, Ireland (en_IE)          2.3
> English, Zimbabwe (en_ZA)         2.3
> Finnish, Finland (fi_FI)          2.3
> Greek, Greece (el_GR)             2.3
> Hebrew, Israel (iw_IL)*           2.3
> Hindi, India (hi_IN)              2.3
> Hungarian, Hungary (hu_HU)        2.3
> Indonesian, Indonesia (in_ID)*    2.3
> Latvian, Latvia (lv_LV)           2.3
> Lithuanian, Lithuania (lt_LT)     2.3
> Norwegian-Bokmol, Norway(nb_NO)   2.3
> Portuguese, Brazil (pt_BR)        2.3
> Portuguese, Portugal (pt_PT)      2.3
> Romanian, Romania (ro_RO)         2.3
> Serbian (sr_RS)                   2.3
> Slovak, Slovakia (sk_SK)          2.3
> Slovenian, Slovenia (sl_SI)       2.3
> Spanish, US (es_US)               2.3
> Swedish, Sweden (sv_SE)           2.3
> Tagalog, Philippines (tl_PH)      2.3
> Thai, Thailand (th_TH)            2.3
> Turkish, Turkey (tr_TR)           2.3
> Ukrainian, Ukraine (uk_UA)        2.3
> Vietnamese, Vietnam (vi_VN)       2.3
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Arabic support was only added in Android 3.0, AKA Honeycomb. The closest you can come to supporting it in Android is to find a compatible [truetype font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueType) and use it.